# Python yield statement returns the same value every time

Tags: python, iterator, yield

EDIT: I want to see the solution using the `next` statement.
I am accessing a weather app API that returns a json object, a part of the information of that object is the daily time of sunrise and sunset, here is its content (for three days):

```
my_dict = {
"daily": [
    {
      "dt": "2020-06-10 12:00:00+01:00",
      "sunrise": "2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00",
      "sunset": "2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00"
    },
    {
        "dt": "2020-06-11 12:00:00+01:00",
        "sunrise": "2020-06-11 05:09:11+01:00",
        "sunset": "2020-06-11 19:48:17+01:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": "2020-06-12 12:00:00+01:00",
      "sunrise": "2020-06-12 05:09:08+01:00",
      "sunset": "2020-06-12 19:48:43+01:00"
    }
]
}
```

And here is the function that should return a tuple per day, but it does not. It keeps returning a tuple of data for the same day, the first day.

```
daily_return = my_dict['daily']


def forecast(daily_return):
    # daily_return is a list
    for day in daily_return:
        # day becomes a dict
        sunrise = day['sunrise']
        sunset = day['sunset']
        yield sunrise, sunset

for i in range(3):
    print(next(forecast(daily_return)))
```

And here is the output:

```
('2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00', '2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00')
('2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00', '2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00')
('2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00', '2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00')
```

Comment: to avoid recreating the generator, created  before the loop ```x = forecast(daily_return)); for i in range(3):
    print(next(x))```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're initiating the generator every time you loop instead of looping a range just iterate the generator:

```
for sunrise, sunset in forecast(daily_return):
    print(sunrise, sunset)
```

If you only want the first 3 you can zip it with a range or use `itertools.islice` as @cs95 has shown:

```
for sunrise, sunset, _ in zip(forecast(daily_return), range(3)):
    print(rise, set)
```

If you must use `next` then initiate the generator outside the loop:

```
gen = forecast(daily_return)
for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen))
```

You can also use `operator.itemgetter` to achieve this same functionality instead of your custom function:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import islice

forecast_gen = map(itemgetter('sunrise', 'sunset'), daily_return)

for sunrise, sunset in islice(forecast_gen, 3):
    print(sunrise, sunset)
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend converting `forecast` to a function that operates on a single entry. You can then call `map` to get an iterator and call `next` on it:

```
def forecast(day):
    return day['sunrise'], day['sunset']

it = map(forecast, daily_return)
print(next(it))
# ('2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00', '2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00')
```

If you want X number of entries from the iterator, use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
list(islice(map(forecast, daily_return), 3))
# [('2020-06-10 05:09:15+01:00', '2020-06-10 19:47:50+01:00'),
#  ('2020-06-11 05:09:11+01:00', '2020-06-11 19:48:17+01:00'),
#  ('2020-06-12 05:09:08+01:00', '2020-06-12 19:48:43+01:00')]
```

Comment: I like your implementation of `islice` I was only trying to stray from importing from another library.

Comment: @Jab Happy to have enriched your day by exactly one `islice`.

Comment: I see what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

Your recreating the generator 3 times, then yield the same first element 3 times. Create the generator before the loop. Simple is better than complex.

```
x = forecast(daily_return))
for i in range(3):
    print(next(x))
```